# On button click Check mark/ tick mark for the selected drop-down options on click show active tick mark

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button like Finish.

When the user clicks on the button the selected option text will show a tick mark or checkmark right side of the selected text with the green color that indicates the user has completed markings for that particular test.

I have tried so many ways but didn't get any luck. The tick mark should not disappear for all the selected options. Any help could be great help full.

Code:

```js
function finish(opt) {
  if (opt.name == retrieveOption()) return;
  document.getElementById("submenu1").innerText = opt.innerText;
  var children = document.getElementById("list").children;
  for (var i of children) {
    var newText = i.innerText.replace(" ✓", "");
    i.innerText = newText;
    i.setAttribute("isSelected", "false");
  }
  opt.innerText += " ✓";
  opt.setAttribute("isSelected", "true");
}
```

```html
<div id='submenu1' class="p-3 sidebar-submenu">
  <select id='list' class="form-control  text-success   col " id="select" editable="true">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select:</option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="optio3">option3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `opt` and where is your button? [mcve]

Comment: `isSelected` is an invalid attribute

Comment: You're replacing the DIVs contents with some text - and than you expect to get elements that do not exist any more

Comment: Use `textContent` instead of `innerText`

Comment: What is `retrieveOption()`?